# Swagger API upload file from php

Tags: php, file-upload, swagger

I am trying to upload files (images) over API (Swagger) using php

I am sending data from template (PHP) and after validation, in controller there is request to API with all parameters.

There are my params (from template)

```
$orderParameter = [
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'category' => 2,
        'file' => $this->request->data['documents_for_upload'][0],
      ];
```

here is response from template

```
[
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Tester',
    'category' => (int) 2,
    'file' => [
        'name' => 'Hydrangeas.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\Users\jwy\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAB7B.tmp',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 595284
    ]
]
```

If I send those data direct (using Swagger UI with browse and select file) than its works, but if I use php I am getting ***error 500***.

In swagger UI `file` field is defined like `Parameter Type = formData` and `Data type = undefined`

I have try to send only `file['tmp_name']` but it doesnt work and also try to convert file `encode_base64` but it is the same result.